# Practicing rogue-wave I/O

Tags: c++, beginner, io

**What I'm doing:**

1. Searching in current directory for a set of files.
2. Filtering the set.
3. Searching through the filtered set of files for a specific line sequence.
4. Write to an output file that line along with the line that directly preceded it and the file in which it is found.

There's no actual purpose to this besides practice, so I'm just reading dummy data. This is my first C++ program and it's especially challenging since it uses the [rogue-wave](http://docs.roguewave.com/legacy-hpp/tlsref/index.html) library rather than much of the standard ones (this runs on an embedded device).

**The program:**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <rw/collstr.h>
#include <rw/sortvec.h>
#include <rw/rstream.h>
#include <rw/regexp.h>

RWSortedVector retrieveFiles();
void searchAndLogFile(RWCollectableString filename, ofstream &outputCSV);

int main()
{
    RWSortedVector fileVecor = retrieveFiles();
    RWCollectableString* file;
    RWSortedVectorIterator next(fileVecor);
    ofstream outputCSV("temp_output.csv");
    while (file = (RWCollectableString*) next()) {
        searchAndLogFile(*(file), outputCSV);
    }
    fileVecor.clearAndDestroy();
    outputCSV.close();

    return 0;
}


void searchAndLogFile(RWCollectableString filename, ofstream &outputCSV)
{
    RWCString line;
    RWCString previousLine;
    ifstream file(filename);
    RWCRegexp re("<TEST>\\.+</TEST>");
    while(line.readLine(file))
    {
        RWCString result = line(re);
        if (result.length() > 0)
        { // if matching line is found
            outputCSV << filename << "," << line << "," << previousLine << endl;
        }
        previousLine = line;
    }
}


// Produces a list of relevant file names
RWSortedVector retrieveFiles()
{
    RWSortedVector fileVector;
    system("dir *.cr | sort > temp.txt");

    RWCString line;
    ifstream file("temp.txt");
    // Regular expression to ensure we only retrieve desired files
    RWCRegexp re("test[0-9]+\\.cr"); 
    while(line.readLine(file))
    {
        RWCString result = line(re);
        if (result.length() > 0)
        { // if file name matches
            fileVector.insert(new RWCollectableString(result));
        }
    }

    file.close();
    system("del temp.txt");
    return fileVector;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. To my knowledge, there's no way to get files in the directory with my constraints. Employing the directory system command with an output file is an effective work-around.

**Concerns:**

1. Direct access to pointers and references is a novel concept and if there's anywhere that its use would benefit.
2. Any error handling I should be doing.